# Reduce multi-level columns into single level by deleting certain levels in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.
data =

```
SAMPLE   MATERIAL   MAT_WEIGHT
SAM1     MAT1       15
SAM1     MAT3       35
SAM1     MAT1       45
SAM2     MAT2       55
SAM2     MAT2       05
```

The real dataframe is much longer.

I applied pivot table like below.

```
table = (pd.pivot_table(data, index = ['SAMPLE'], 
columns = ['MATERIAL'], values = ['MAT_WEIGHT'], 
aggfunc = {'MAT_WEIGHT':np.sum})).fillna(0)
```

and got the table like below.
table =

```
       MAT_WEIGHT

MATERIAL    MAT1    MAT2    MAT3    MAT4                                                                            

SAMPLE

SAM1        100     50      80     30
SAM2        80      50      120    25
SAM3        78      58      65     25
```

I want to reduce the table to a single level column from multiple levels.
The final dataframe that I want looks like below.

table_final =

```
SAMPLE     MAT1     MAT2    MAT3    MAT4                                                                            
SAM1        100     50      80     30
SAM2        80      50      120    25
SAM3        78      58      65     25
```

How to do this?
(The numerical values given here are for visualization purpose only and not exact.)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using column names under lists to avoid `MultiIndex` from [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), also add `fill_value` parameter:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(data, 
                       index ='SAMPLE', 
                       columns = 'MATERIAL', 
                       values = 'MAT_WEIGHT', 
                       aggfunc = np.sum,
                       fill_value=0)

print (table)
MATERIAL  MAT1  MAT2  MAT3
SAMPLE                    
SAM1        60     0    35
SAM2         0    60     0
```

Last for index to column and remove column name is possible use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
table = table.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would solve it:

```
table_final = table.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

With your final table looking like:

```
           MAT1     MAT2    MAT3    MAT4    
SAMPLE                                                                                
SAM1        100     50      80     30
SAM2        80      50      120    25
SAM3        78      58      65     25
```